# Could not find module in path: 'react/jsx-runtime' relative to '@mui/styled-engine/StyledEngineProvider/StyledEngineProvider.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am having this error while creating a new React project with [MUI](https://mui.com/). I copied [this](https://mui.com/components/buttons/#basic-button) code example from the docs which works on their live Codesandbox but not in my local. This is the full [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DytMW.png):

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Could not find module in path: 'react/jsx-runtime' relative to '/node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/StyledEngineProvider/StyledEngineProvider.js'
```

Below is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "title": "BasicButtons Material Demo",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start"
  },
  "name": "BasicButtons Material Demo",
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "11.6.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.6.0",
    "@mui/material": "5.1.1",
    "@types/react": "16.14.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.14",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.0-beta"
  }
}
```

Comment: resolved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76561254/6318705

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per [docs](https://mui.com/getting-started/supported-platforms/#react), **MUI v5** only supports React v17+:

> MUI supports the most recent versions of React, starting with ^17.0.0 (the one with event delegation at the React root). Have a look at the older versions for backward compatibility.

The actual reason why this error shows up is because [`react/jsx-runtime`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html) module only exists in React v17. If you're stuck with v15 or v16 of React, you can update `react` and `react-dom` to the latest minor version to fix the error.

Update both packages to the latest version (17+) to fix it:

```
npm install react@latest react-dom@latest
```

If you have to use v16

```
npm install react@16.14.0 react-dom@16.14.0
```

If you have to use v15

```
npm install react@15.7.0 react-dom@15.7.0
```

Comment: a ton of thanks, this was exactly my issue