# unable to resolve module react/jsx-runtime

Tags: react-native, node-modules

[image]

"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
"expo": "^44.0.1",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.64.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
"react-native-paper": "^4.11.1",
"react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
"react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
"react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.6.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
},

Comment: Another solution may be to use absolute paths. E.g. instead of importing from "@react-navigation/native", you might have to use "@react-navigation/native.mjs". Source: [#20235 Facebook React](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/20235#issue-741698020)

Comment: resolved in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76561254/6318705

Answer (score 8):

React 17 introduce a new feature `New JSX Transform`. In short, `JSX Transform` can make you write `react` without `import React from 'react'`. However, the new feature is introduced in React 17 and supported for React 16.14.0, React 15.7.0. `"react": "^16.13.1"` is not compatible with the new feature, so you should upgrade your react version.

###### Reference

1. [Introducing the New JSX Transform](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)

Comment: Thank-you!  The fix for me was to upgrade from React 16.9 to 16.14 (which is _newer_).

Answer (score 1):

Updating your react version possibily can resolve your problem. Command line: npm install --save react@latest.

Comment: Thanks, I tried after deleteting node modules folder and package-lock.json file and run npm install resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Try do delete all these files:

- *node_modules*
- *package-lock.json*
- *ios/Pods*
- *ios/Podfile.lock*
- *ios/build*

Then run:

```
npm start --reset-cache
```

Finally:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```